# How to move chromedriver from download folder to /usr/local/bin?

Tags: macos, terminal, selenium-chromedriver

How to move chromedriver from download folder to /usr/local/bin, when it said "permission denied" at the Terminal? I am using Mac.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/54064/288199

Comment: I tried mv ~/Downloads/chromedriver sudo cp /usr/local/bin And it did not work. Please help.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2GBO_QjRlo&t=134s

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. Please help me fix it so that I can understand the subject.

Comment: try with "sudo mv ~/Downloads/chromedriver /usr/local/bin" you can also install chromedriver using homebrew